# How can I see planets with my telescope?

Tags: planet, amateur-observing

I have bought a Celestron Astromaster 130 telescope and I am relatively new to astronomy, when I tried to view Jupiter a few months ago I could not make out any details. It was just a white orb. Any help with getting clearer images and any advice on viewing. I live on a main road BTW and that's where I was viewing from.